# Как называется текст закодированный функцией escape() браузера Microsoft Internet Explorer

Tags: c, linux

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Нужно какое-то короткое название.

Это один из вариантов [URLEncode и URLDecode](http://www.codenet.ru/services/urlencode-urldecode/).

А фактически нужно название для пары функций кодирующих-раскодирующих Cntrl и "пробелы" в строках типа

```
" x\ny"
```

в

```
%20x%0Ay%00  (это если задать длину 5)
```

(*в гугле не забанили, просто надоело искать. Если кто знает - напишите, специально напрягаться и искать не надо.*)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[percent-encoded](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.1) ? согласно RFC-3986

Comment: Спасибо! 

Отлично, тогда имена (прямо из RFC) будут `pct_encode()` и `pct_decode()`.